# CommonJS alternative to ES6's importing as alias

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

ES6 can *import an export as alias*, like so;

```
import express from 'express'
import { express as playground } from 'graphql-playground/middleware'
```

Is there an alternative way to do this with CommonJS `require('something')`? Or something that circumvents the above declaration issue if it were done the CommonJS way?

This throws an error.

```
const express = require('express')
const express = require('graphql-playground/middleware')

// SyntaxError: Identifier 'express' has already been declared
```

Comment: Can't you just assign it to a variable with a different name? You haven't shown a CommonJS example, so it's hard to give suggestions of what to change.

Comment: Like `const express = require('express'); const playground = require('graphql-playground/middleware').express;` ? Not sure understand your problem.

Comment: Yes @FelixKling, that's exactly what I was needing. Thank you, and sorry for the poor explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CommonJS is really just assigning values to variables and you can name the variables however you want:

```
const express = require('express');
const playground = require('graphql-playground/middleware').express;
```

Answer (score 3):

For non-default exports (module.export = var) you can also alias with regular destructure syntax:

```
const {
  originName: newNameInFile
} = require('foo.js')
```